# Tela de Login no PHP não acessa o painel

Tags: php, login, autenticação

Estou iniciando na programação e tenho que fazer um projeto de página de login, mas por algum motivo ela não está acessando o painel, mesmo com as informações de login corretas.

Código da página de login:

````
include('conexao.php');

if (isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_POST['senha'])) {

    if (strlen($_POST['email']) == 0) {
        echo "Preencha seu e-mail";
    } else if (strlen($_POST['senha']) == 0) {
        echo "Preencha sua senha";
    } else {

        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $senha = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

        $sql_code = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";
        $sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die("Falha na execução do código SQL: " . $mysqli->error);

        $quantidade = $sql_query->num_rows;

        if ($quantidade == 1) {

            $usuario = $sql_query->fetch_assoc();

            if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
                session_start();
            }

            $_SESSION['id'] = $usuario['id'];
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $usuario['nome'];

            header("Location: painel.php");

        } else {
            echo "Falha ao logar! E-mail ou senha incorretos";
        }

    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <h2>Faça login</h2>
        <label>Seu email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Seu e-mail">
        <label>Sua senha:</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="sua senha">

        <button type="submit" class="botao">Fazer login</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>```

conexao.php

```<?php

$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$database = 'login';
$host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $database);

if($mysqli->error) {
    die("Falha ao conectar ao banco de dados: " . $mysqli->error);
}

?>```
````

Comment: Chegou a debugar o código para ver se está chegando até o header location? no painel.php não tem nenhuma validação que possa estar redirecionando para o login novamente?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fiz correções no seu script, veja se está funcional agora.

Login:

```
<?php

$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$database = 'teste';
$host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $database);

if($mysqli->error) {
    die("Falha ao conectar ao banco de dados: " . $mysqli->error);
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['senha']);

    if (!empty($senha) && !empty($email)) {

        try {
            $sql_code = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = '{$email}' AND senha = '{$senha}'");


            if ($sql_code->num_rows > 0) {
                session_start();
                $usuario = $sql_code->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $usuario['id'];
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $usuario['nome'];
                header("Location: painel.php");
            } else {
                echo "Falha ao logar! E-mail ou senha incorretos";
            }
        }catch(\Exeption $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="senha">
    <button>Entrar </button>
</form>
```

Painel:

```
<?php

session_start();

$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$database = 'teste';
$host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $database);

if($mysqli->error) {
    die("Falha ao conectar ao banco de dados: " . $mysqli->error);
}



if(!isset($_SESSION['nome'])){
    die("Você precisa logar no sistema");
}
?>

<h1> Entrou </h1>
```

Não estou usando criptografia no login, mas o correto é usar pelo menos o md5, dê uma pesquisada ou então o hash.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.md5.php

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Funcionou. Sobre a criptografia, como não foi exigido e eu não tenho muito conhecimento, eu optei por não colocar, mas vou dar uma pesquisada aqui, valeu!